# Using historical flight data to predict reliability of airline

Tags: air-travel, airlines, cancellations

I'm not sure if I can name the website, but I paid some small amount of money to access the historical flight data for KRU2609. I can see the information on flights since 19th of January 2022.

The following confuses me:

- Many Iranian airlines regularly have cancellations. I don't see any in the past 3 months. Does this mean that there are none, or would these flights somehow fall through the radar (haha)? (I note that there are only 6 flights for March, perhaps the remaining flights were cancelled and dont appear on the website to begin with?
- Relatedly, there are some flights with unknown status. Are these cancellations? Why would the website have the information for some flights but not others?
- Finally, the difference between the scheduled and actual time for departure is wild: For February and match, the ATD is always about one hour *before* the STD. In April, the ATD and STD are identical, on the minute. The time of arrival always is exactly as scheduled. What is the source on these information, and how can I use them?

Comment: I have seen that airlines have learned to hide their cancellations. Not sure what they do, but I have seen flights that get delayed and then cancelled (which they really were, a friend was supposed to fly on them) disappear from google, flightstats, flightaware, etc. the next day. Now it looks like there was never a flight scheduled for that day.

Comment: _My goal is to predict the likelihood of a future flight either being cancelled or delayed significantly_ Sorry, but you are looking at something with too many variables here, including bad data and outside events, you aren't ever going to get anything reliable.

Comment: @Moo The last 2 years have certainly confirmed that. Any predictions based on data prior to March 2020 are totally useless now. And even after things got sort-of back to normal, they have varied a lot due to: pilot shortages in some airlines, changing testing and other requirements (especially for international flights), war (which has affected not just the countries involved but many others due to inability to fly over large parts of the world), various airplane models grounded which affected some airlines quite a bit, etc. And that's on top of the usual inconsistent weather.

Comment: This sort of model wouldn't even capture the most relevant feature to predicting cancellations -- whether a COVID wave is happening.  Anything you come up with won't be any better than flipping a coin.

Comment: Your concerns are completely irrelevant for this specific flight, but I have removed the "goal" from the question as to stop this sidetracking discussion and focus on the specific questions at hand.